# How do i plot computations of data from a mySQL database using python

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to create a bar chart using python that sums the total of a column based on the conditions in another column in a mySQL database.

i have created a mySQL database of personnel spending in which one column is categories of spend e.g Food and another column is amount e.g £5.00. I would like to create a bar chart which totals my spending by category.

I can ok with connecting between python and mySQL and for simple barcharts but its the sum computation that I'm struggling with.

Thanks

Comment: what did you try? Do you know SQL - ie. `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`? Something like `SELECT SUM(spending) GROUP BY category`. Eventually you could load to `pandas.DataFrame` and  use `.group_by()` and `.sum()`. Something like `df.group_by('category').sum('spending')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get total value using directly SQL - something like

```
SELECT SUM(spending) GROUP BY category
```

I don't have example database to test it and to show full working code.

---

Eventually you could load all data to `pandas.DataFrame` (`df`) and use similar

```
result = df.groupby('category').sum('spending')
```

With `pandas` you can also directly display it using `matplotlib`

```
result.plot.bar()
```

---

Minimal working code with example data

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'spending': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
})

result = df.groupby('category').sum('spending')
print(result)

result.plot.bar()

plt.savefig('output.jpg')  # save before show
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
          spending
category          
A                5
B                2
C                8
```

[image]

Eventually you can use `result` to generate some plot on HTML but it would need extra JavaScript library. Or you can use image 'output.jpg' in HTML.